# list of cities and international airports

Tags: webforms, forms

Drupal has the built in option for forms which provide complete list of countries. What if we require a complete list of cities for each country and the list of international airports. Do we need to insert that all manually, or there is a way to aggregate it from other sites.

Comment: I don't know about drupal module for this. http://openflights.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/openflights/openflights/data/airlines.dat This link contains all the airport. You can find more info here. http://openflights.org/data.html

Comment: I understand the close-as-off-topic votes, but on second thought, this is a relevant question if you look at the general problem of having to add pre-defined lists of select options. I don't know of a module that does exactly this, but there is a [List field predefined options](http://drupal.org/project/list_predefined_options) module which makes it easier to manage pre-defined option lists. Maybe you can extend it using the list @TylerDurden linked to.

Comment: @marcvangend Questions about resources are off-topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was not actually asking for a resource, may the last part of the question has made some confusion. Any ways will try to be more careful next time.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I know. It looks like you didn't really try to understand what I'm saying, but please go ahead and close the question before the OP has had the opportunity to clarify.

Comment: You question is, "or is there any website from where we can get these lists?" You are asking for a website where you can get a list of cities or international airports. In other words, you are asking for online resources. Getting such a list is then not Drupal specific.

Comment: @marcvangend If the OP is asking something different from a website listing all the cities, and international airports, he can edit the question to make it clear. The OP has all the time to clarify that, and closing a question doesn't stop the OP from clarifying his question; in fact, a closed question is still editable, and can be re-opened if it becomes an acceptable question. Users who vote to close a question can also vote to re-open it.

Comment: @marcvangend Thank you for the suggestion. It really seems to be a nice module, I am just going to give it a try.

Comment: @TylerDurden Thank you for pointing such a wonderful lists. But how can we use that in webform. Webform select list allows maximum 500 options and if I am copying and pasting that list in autocomplete webform widget it gives me a huge error. Please suggest how to use these list in webform.

Comment: @marcvangend Can you please tell how to add our options list using this module. I am unable to locate any UI to create option lists for later use

Comment: @Fahad There is no UI, you need to implement a hook in a custom module. See the list_predefined_options.api.php file for documentation, or ask for help in the [project's issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/list_predefined_options).